# ¿Comó redirigir a un perfil determinado?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy creando una página donde se muestran todos los perfiles con sus respectivos datos, para ello he creado tres tablas: `usuarios`, `datos` y `conocer`.

En la consulta las he relacionado mediante `INNER JOIN`. Hasta aquí todo perfecto: se muestran todos los perfiles con sus respectivos datos.

El problema se me crea justo en el enlace `ver perfil`: me redirecciona al perfil del usuario **que está logueado** y no al perfil que se solicitó. Por ejemplo, el usuario que está en la viendo la página tiene el id 5 y desea ver el perfil del id 3 al hacer *click* en el enlace me lleva al perfil del id 5, aunque en barra de direcciones me aparezca la dirección `http://localhost/myfantasy/miperfil.php?id=3`

He cambiado los valores del id en el enlace, he cambiado la consulta de `INNER JOIN` por `LEFT JOIN`, he cambiado todos los `JOIN` que encontré en internet. He puesto condicionales `WHERE` y ha sido peor porque no se me muestran los datos o se me muestra solamente el perfil del usuario logueado o no se me muestra nada.

He tratado de hacer las consultas independientes por cada tabla y solo me muestra errores. Lo cierto es que me encuentro atascado totalmente, ya llevo bastante tiempo tratando de solucionarlo y aún no sé cual es mi error.

Aquí les dejo los códigos de las páginas perfiles y miperfil

Página perfiles.php

````
    ```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>perfiles</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/perfiles.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="fondo">

             <?php        

            session_start();
            if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
            } else {
            ?>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                window.location = "./index.html";
              </script>
            <?php
            }

            include '../conexion/cone.php';

            $id = $con->real_escape_string($_SESSION['id']);

            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios t1 INNER JOIN datos t2 ON t1.id_usuario = 
            t2.id_datos 
            INNER JOIN conocer t3 ON t1.id_usuario = t2.id_datos = id_preferencias  ORDER BY 
            id_usuario LIMIT 0,5;";

            $resultado = $con->query($consulta);

            while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
            ?>
                <div class="perfil">
                    <div class="container" id="container">
                        <div class="section_container">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="columna">
                                    <p>
                                        <img src="../images/<?php echo $valores['foto']; ?>" 
                                         alt="<?php echo $valores['nickname']; ?>">
                                    <h3><?php echo $valores['nickname']; ?></h3>
                                    <h4><?php echo $valores['edad']; ?></h4>
                                    <h4><?php echo $valores['pais']; ?></h4>
                                    <h4><?php echo $valores['provincia']; ?></h4>
                                    <p> 
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing 
                                        elit. Aperiam possimus necessitatibus
                                        at
                                        deserunt impedit aliquam optio labore, excepturi 
                                        temporibus fuga quos cumque sapiente
                                        expedita voluptas quo reprehenderit sit doloribus 
                                        officia?
                                    </p>
                                    </p>
                                    <a class="boton" href="../miperfil.php?id=<?php echo 
                                    $valores['id_usuario']; ?>;">Ver Perfil</a>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php
            }
                ?>
                </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>

    ```
````

Página miperfil

````
    ```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">

    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title>miperfil</title> 
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/miperfil.css">
    </head> 

    <body>  

      <div class="fondo">   

        <?php

        include './conexion/cone.php';

        session_start();

        if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        } else {
        ?>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = "../index.html";
          </script>
        <?php
        }

        $id = $con->real_escape_string($_SESSION['id']);

        $consulta = "SELECT t1.nickname, t1.pais, t1.provincia, t1.foto, t2.edad, t2.sexo, 
        t2.orientacion_sex, t2.deseo, t2.edad_min, t2.edad_max, t3.orientacion, t3.gustos
        FROM usuarios t1 INNER JOIN datos t2 ON t1.id_usuario = t2.id_datos 
        INNER JOIN conocer t3 ON t1.id_usuario = t3.id_preferencias WHERE email = '$id';";

        $resultado = $con->query($consulta);

        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        ?>

         <div class="container" id="container">
            <div class="section_container">
              <fieldset>
                <div class="columna">
                  <div><img class="imgen" src="./images/<?php echo $valores['foto'] ?>" alt=" 
                  <?php 
                       echo $valores['nickname']; ?>"></div>
                  <div>
                    <h1 class="name"><?php echo $valores['nickname']; ?></h1>
                    <h2 class="age"><?php echo $valores['edad'];;?></h2>
                    <h2 class="country"><?php echo $valores['pais']; ?></h2>
                    <h2 class="city"><?php echo $valores['provincia']; ?></h2>
                  </div><br>
                  <div class="cambio">
                    <h2><a href="./php/cambiarfoto.php">Cambiar foto de perfil</a></h2>
                  </div>

                  <div class="parraf">
                    <div class="datos">
                     <h2 class="dat">Sexo : <?php echo $valores['sexo']; ?></h2>
                     <h2 class="ori"> <?php echo $valores['orientacion_sex']; ?></h2>
                  </div>
                    <div class="desea">
                      <h2 class="dat">Desea : <?php echo $valores['deseo'] ?></h2>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                      <h2 class="dat">Quiere conocer :</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <h2 class="dat"><?php echo $valores['orientacion'] ?></h2>
                    </div>
                   <div>
                      <h2 class="dat">Le gusta :</h2>
                   </div>
                   <div class="checkbox">
                      <h2 class="dat"><?php echo $valores['gustos'] ?></h2>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="foot">
                    <div class="foot1"><img class="chat" src="./assets/iconos/1486164749- 
                     120_79719.png" alt="chat"></div>
                    <div class="foot2"><img class="corazon" id="corazon" 
                     src="./assets/iconos/favorite_favorite_fav_favorite_11232.png" 
                           alt="favorito"> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="foot3"><img class="mensage" 
                     src="./assets/iconos/messagemail_mensaje_9474.png" alt="mensaje"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
         </div>
        <?php
         }     
        ?>  
      </div>

      <script src="../assets/jquery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../assets/js/mostrarperfiles.js"></script>

    </body>

    </html>

    ```
````

Comment: El sitio tiene un [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) como apartados tales [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) que deberías visitar. He eliminado todo el *ruido* (no aporta **absolutamente nada**) y formateado un poco.

Comment: Por otra parte, utilizas etiquetas dispares: `PHP` y `MYSQL`. ¿ No has podido siquiera determinar si el problema está en tus consultas o en tu código PHP ? Si sabes donde está el problema, elimina todo lo no necesario/relacionado de la pregunta. Te sugiero consultar lo que es un [mcve].

Comment: No estás asignando correctamente la variable $id, pues lo haces así: `$id = $con->real_escape_string($_SESSION['id']);` y según parece eso es un email del usuario **logueado** (pues en la consulta lo usas asi: `WHERE email = '$id';`) y no del id de usuario pasado con la url.  Cambia eso por : `$id = $_GET['id_usuario']` y el where de la consulta por `WHERE id_usuario = $id` y a ver si con eso lo arreglas

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por responder @masterguru. Eso que Ud me aconseja ya lo intenté y me arroja un error de undefine index: id_usuario.

Comment: Si, me confundi, debes usar `$id = $_GET['id'];` por un lado, y hacer el cambio del WHERE que te dije antes, es decir, que quede así: `WHERE id_usuario = $id`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por responder nuevamente. Funcionó, ahora los perfiles se muestran correctamente pero cuando entro al perfil directamente desde el login me envía el Undefined index: id. Nuevamente muchísimas gracias por responder.

Comment: Vale, pues cámbia `if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {` por:  `if (isset($_GET['id'])) {` y prueba de nuevo

Comment: No, no funciona. Me arroja el mismo error. Nuevamente muchísimas gracias por responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás sacando el id de la sesión en lugar de la que envías por querystring

Cambia esto:

```
$id = $con->real_escape_string($_SESSION['id']);
```

Por esto

```
$id = $con->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

Cualquier duda me comentas

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por responder estimado @Pushuno. Ya intenté hacer lo que Ud me sugiere pero eso me arroja dos errores, el primero un Undifined variable _Get y el segundo un Trying to access array offset on value of Type null, ambos en la misma línea 73. ¿Podría ser que el error se provoque por la forma en que inicio session?

Comment: Estimadísima @Trauma muchísimas gracias por responder. Lamento mucho no haber sabido formular mi pregunta, ya hice el recorrido que Ud me sugirió, le prometo para la próxima redactaré mejor mi pregunta. Y como Ud bien dice no he podido determinar donde está el problema, como mencioné anteriormente 
estoy aprendiendo, pero creo que de saberlo no hubiese formulado la pregunta. También lamento mucho no haber entendido muy claramente su respuesta. De cualquier forma muchísimas gracias por responder.

Comment: @JulioCésar pásame que tenes en la línea 73. Podes testear abrir el archivo php desde el navegador y pasándole el ?id=5 a ver qué te tira o abriendo el network del navegador a ver a qué url estás mandando el request.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por volver a responder @Pushuno. Lo que hay en la linea 73 es lo que sugeriste: $id = $con->real_escape_string($_GET['id']); en cuanto a lo del testeo, me trae la misma notificación y disculpa mi ignorancia pero no sé que es el networking. Recuerda que estoy aprendiendo y no sé casi nada o prácticamente nada. Nuevamente muchas gracias

Comment: Perfecto, asegurate que el get este en mayusculas $_GET["id"], las comillas pueden ser simples o dobles da igual. En el caso que el id no llegue correctamtente en la peticion te va a devolver el error de que no encuentra el valor id.
Entra desde tu navegador a http://localhost/myfantasy/miperfil.php?id=3 y deberias obtener el resultado deseado, si eso funciona ok testealo desde tu front.
Para ver el network desde el navegador apretas F12 y vas a tener una solapa "network" donde ves todas las peticiones.
Cualquier duda me consultas

Comment: Una vez  muchísimas gracias por responder. Me he asegurado de que todo este bien escrito. He puesto la dirección directamente en el navegador y como bien supones me ha vuelto a arrojar el mismo error. En cuanto al "network" lamento volver a defraudarte pero el f12 solo me activa el modo avión, he probado con todos f y ninguno me da nada, ni el f5 me refresca la página. Parece ser un problema de la configuración de mi laptop. Nuevamente muchísimas gracias por responder.

Comment: Compartime el codigo que lo testeo

Comment: Discúlpame, pero como te envió el código ¿Por aquí mismo por los comentarios? El código que está arriba es el mismo que estoy usando. Solo hay que cambiarle la variable $_SESSION por $_GET. Nuevamente muchísimas gracias por responder.

Comment: estamos hablando del archivo miperfil.php no? lo que te dijo masterguru en el mensaje de mas arriba del WHERE id_usuario = $id es asi, podes editar la pregunta principal y agregar capturas del error y numeros de linea del codigo, eso ayudaria mucho

Comment: Ya está solucionado. Muchísimas gracias a todos.

Comment: Cual era el problema?. comentalo aca asi si le pasa a alguien lo ayuda

Comment: Como no estimado @pashuno. Como te había comentado desde el principio. Era la forma en que estaba iniciando session.